# Linux/OpenJDK/IcedTea : debugging browser-hosted applet

Tags: linux, applet, java, icedtea

Did anyone ever pull that trick off?

I am trying to do something like

```
$ ICEDTEAPLUGIN_DEBUG=true; firefox
```

but nothing listens on port 8787. [The docs](http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/IcedTea-Web#Debugging) say this should work for me.

**Please don't suggest switching from OpenJDK to Oracle JVM**: this is okay but off the topic.

I am not sure that correct plugin is there, but it should be so, as I'd done some tracing setup and see proper messages in

```
~/.icedtea/logs
```

My current jre/jdk packages are listed below (Ubuntu Maverick).

```
$ dpkg -l "*jdk*" "*jre*" "*icedtea*"
un  cacao-oj6-jre                        <none>                               (no description available)
ii  default-jdk                          1:1.6-40ubuntu1                      Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit
ii  default-jre                          1:1.6-40ubuntu1                      Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime
ii  default-jre-headless                 1:1.6-40ubuntu1                      Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime (headless)
ii  gcj-4.5-jre-lib                      4.5.2-8ubuntu1                       Java runtime library for use with gcj (jar files)
un  gcj-jre                              <none>                               (no description available)
ii  icedtea-6-jre-cacao                  6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1         Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Cacao
ii  icedtea-6-jre-jamvm                  6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1         Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using JamVM
un  icedtea-gcjwebplugin                 <none>                               (no description available)
ii  icedtea-netx                         1.1.1-0ubuntu1~11.04.1               NetX - implementation of the Java Network Launching Protocol (JNLP)
ii  icedtea-plugin                       1.1.1-0ubuntu1~11.04.1               web browser plugin based on OpenJDK and IcedTea to execute Java applets
un  icedtea6-jre-cacao                   <none>                               (no description available)
ii  icedtea6-plugin                      6b21.1.1-0ubuntu1~11.04.1            web browser plugin to execute Java applets (dependency package)
un  jre                                  <none>                               (no description available)
un  openjdk-6-dbg                        <none>                               (no description available)
un  openjdk-6-demo                       <none>                               (no description available)
un  openjdk-6-doc                        <none>                               (no description available)
ii  openjdk-6-jdk                        6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1         OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
ii  openjdk-6-jre                        6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1         OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-6-jre-headless               6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1         OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
ii  openjdk-6-jre-lib                    6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1         OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
un  openjdk-6-jre-zero                   <none>                               (no description available)
ii  openjdk-6-source                     6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1         OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files
un  sun-java5-jre                        <none>                               (no description available)
un  sun-java6-jdk                        <none>                               (no description available)
un  sun-java6-jre                        <none>                               (no description available)
```

Comment: I've already replicated the parameters I need via local IDE launch. So no bounty for this one, as it does not burn my ass anymore. I'd welcome and vote up any sane ideas on this matter anyway, as some other poor dev may get stuck on this issue sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't setting the environment variable properly.

```
ICEDTEAPLUGIN_DEBUG=true; firefox
```

You have a semicolon, so you're setting the environment variable in the *current* shell -- in particular this will *not* pass the ICEDTEAPLUGIN_DEBUG variable to the firefox subprocess.  What you actually want is this:

```
ICEDTEAPLUGIN_DEBUG=true firefox
```